# How to show someone else's webcam when visiting a page in asp.net using WebRTC, Signalr

Tags: asp.net, signalr, webrtc

I am building video call in asp.net Webform, signalr, WebRTC.
Specifically, my idea is as follows:

**I have a Page1.aspx page. When users visit this page, they can see videos from each other's webcams.**

Page1.aspx

```
<ul id="_listvideouser" class="gap15"></ul>
<input id="hdtempIDUser" type="hidden" runat="server" />


<script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    var userId = $('#hdtempIDUser').val();;
    $(function () {
        const hub = $.connection.videoHub;

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            startLocalVideoStream();
        });

        const localVideo = document.createElement('video');
        const remoteVideos = new Map(); //

        // When receiving a video stream from someone else
        hub.client.receiveVideoStream = function (userId, videoStream) {
            if (!remoteVideos[userId]) {
                remoteVideos[userId] = videoStream;
                const li = $('<li data-user-id=' + userId + '></li>');
                const remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
                remoteVideo.srcObject = videoStream;
                remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
                li.append(remoteVideo);
                $('#_listvideouser').append(li);
            }
        };

    
        // Process video stream from current user
        function startLocalVideoStream() {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
                .then(function (stream) {
                    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
                    localVideo.autoplay = true;
                    // Gửi video stream đến hub
                    hub.server.sendVideoStream(userId, stream);

                    const li = $('<li data-user-id=' + userId + '></li>');
                    li.append(localVideo);
                    $('#_listvideouser').append(li);
                    // offer, handle ICE candidates, ...
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.error('Error accessing webcam:', error);
                });
        }
    });
</script>
```

VideoHub.cs

```
public class VideoHub : Hub
{
    public void SendVideoStream(string userId, string videoStream)
    {
        Clients.Others.ReceiveVideoStream(userId, videoStream);
    }
}
```

**Now it shows my videoStream. However when another user accesses Page1 I don't get the videoStream from the new user? I tried processing in the code:**

```
hub.client.receiveVideoStream = function (userId, videoStream) {
    if (!remoteVideos[userId]) {
        remoteVideos[userId] = videoStream;
        const li = $('<li data-user-id=' + userId + '></li>');
        const remoteVideo = document.createElement('video');
        remoteVideo.srcObject = videoStream;
        remoteVideo.autoplay = true;
        li.append(remoteVideo);
        $('#_listvideouser').append(li);
    }
};
```

However it still doesn't work, I also checked in console it doesn't give any error.

Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you!